# Oracle creating Table using super class attribute as primary key

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, relational-database

I have a sales_person_type defined as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE sales_person_type UNDER person_type (
     salesAppointments     sales_person_appointments
);
```

this is a subclass of the person_type defined as such:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE person_type AS OBJECT (
   personID           NUMBER,
   forename             VARCHAR2(30),
   surname              VARCHAR2(20),
   dateOfBirth          DATE
) NOT FINAL;
```

I'm trying to create a table of sales persons and specifying the primary key as the super class attribute like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sales_person_table OF sales_person_type (  
  PRIMARY KEY (personID),
  OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS PRIMARY KEY)                       
  NESTED TABLE salesAppointments STORE AS sale_appointment_table (  
    (PRIMARY KEY(NESTED_TABLE_ID, appointmentID))             
    ORGANIZATION INDEX COMPRESS)                         
  RETURN AS LOCATOR
```

But I'm getting this error:

> SQL Error: ORA-02330: datatype specification not allowed
>   02330. 00000 -  "datatype specification not allowed"
>   *Cause:    An attempt was made to specify the data type in the column
>              constraint specification of an object table.

I'm think it's because im trying to assign the primary key as the super class attibute? Is this the correct syntax for this?

Cheers.

EDIT:

Works now, thanks Dimitry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the syntax of CREATE TABLE for OID clause:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE person_type AS OBJECT (
  2     personID           NUMBER,
  3     forename             VARCHAR2(30),
  4     surname              VARCHAR2(20),
  5     dateOfBirth          DATE
  6  ) NOT FINAL;
  7  /

SQL>  create or replace type sale_appointment is object
  2   (
  3     appointmentID integer
  4   );
  5  /

Тип создан.

SQL> create type sales_person_appointments as table of sale_appointment;
  2  /


SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE sales_person_type UNDER person_type (
  2       salesAppointments     sales_person_appointments
  3  );
  4  /

SQL> CREATE TABLE sales_person_table OF sales_person_type (
  2    PRIMARY KEY (personID)
  3  )
  4  OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS PRIMARY KEY
  5  NESTED TABLE salesAppointments STORE AS sale_appointment_table (
  6  (PRIMARY KEY(NESTED_TABLE_ID, appointmentID))
  7   ORGANIZATION INDEX COMPRESS)
  8   RETURN AS LOCATOR
  9  /

Table created.
```